# Is there default support for lazy loading in Restkit?

Tags: ios, lazy-loading, restkit

I am using Restkit 0.20 in my ios application. For every request, server responds with a json array containing hundreds of objects which takes lot of time to map/load. Is there default support for lazy loading the objects in Restkit?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably accomplish what you want to do by using CoreData.

RestKit lets you map CoreData entities to objects returned back from a REST call. These objects will get stored locally in a CoreData store that you specify.

Then, what you could do is just pull the objects from the CoreData store, if you don't want to make the web-service call. It doesn't do this automatically for you, but it's not that hard to do.